# Why does my Lambda function timeout connecting to SES VPC Endpoint?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ses, amazon-vpc

[Since April 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-simple-email-service-ses-for-vpc-endpoints/), AWS supports VPC endpoints for SES (Simple Email Service.)  Despite this,  I cannot get a Lambda to communicate with SES using the endpoint.  It always times out.  Perhaps this is because the SES VPC Endpoints are only supported for EC2 instances in the VPC and not for Lambdas?

I have my infrastructure describe using Terraform, as described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/carlgieringer/b4ccca1e5f1c6a7b91cc4215b78595f2).  [`ses_lambda.tf`](https://gist.github.com/carlgieringer/b4ccca1e5f1c6a7b91cc4215b78595f2#file-ses_lambda-tf) defines the infrastructure and basically implements [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints.html).  [`sesTest.js`](https://gist.github.com/carlgieringer/b4ccca1e5f1c6a7b91cc4215b78595f2#file-sestest-js) is my Lambda function. [`terraform-show.out`](https://gist.github.com/carlgieringer/b4ccca1e5f1c6a7b91cc4215b78595f2#file-terraform-show-out) shows the result of `terraform show` limited just to the resources defined by `ses_lambda.tf`.

As you can see in `ses_lambda.tf`, the SES Endpoint's security group allows all traffic on any SMTP port (25, 465, 587, 2465, or 2587) from any IP in the VPC's CIDR block.  So I'm confused about why this doesn't work...

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I think the workaround is to treat the endpoint as SMTP, not an AWS SES API.

Comment: And my solution was: post a message to SNS, use a non-VPC lambda to read from the SNS topic, then call SES from that lambda.

Answer (score 14):

It looks like SES VPC endpoints are SMTP endpoints not SES API endpoints. [The guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints.html) is not explicit about it but it does mention SMTP ports and endpoints.

I created an endpoint and the private DNS name it produced was email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (SMTP). SDK tries to connect to email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (SES API).

It appears that the solution is to either use SMTP or setup NAT Gateway.

**Update:** Confirming that SMTP works over SES VPC endpoint in Lambda (as exptected).

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. Which endpoint you used? Did you try with SMTP endpoint?

Comment: I second the request for more elaboration on this.

Comment: If you happen to have an EC2 instance running in your VPC another workaround is to install a web proxy like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and proxy the AWS API requests in the Lambda function.

Answer (score 4):

I was having difficulties with the same setup. The reality is that nzhuk98's answer is the solution but for someone who didn't have experience with this - it did not make sense to me too.

You cannot use AWS SDK's SES methods, even if you adjust the `endpoint` setting to the Private DNS that was given to you after the VPC endpoint was created.

AWS SDK's SES method uses `https` only, and the VPC endpoint exposes only the SMTP port of the SES Service. Therefore, you need to opt-out from using AWS SDK completely and switch to something like Nodemailer.

This is what I did https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#1-single-connection

I hope this is useful for the next person that is looking for this.

Comment: If you have a lambda function running in the default AWS VPC instead of your custom one and is able to access internet but not SES - this is probably why. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I hear AWS timeout issues, the first thing I check is always IAM. Does the Lambda function have an IAM Policy and Execution Role that grants the appropriate permissions to access SES within your account?

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/

Comment: That link doesn't mention SES VPC Endpoints.  It does list three requirements: "1) AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) permissions for Lambda to execute the API call. 2) A verified Amazon SES identity (domain or email address). 3) A Lambda function with logic for sending email via Amazon SES."  I have satisfied all of these, but it still isn't working.`ses_send_email` is the IAM policy granting SES permssions, and it is attached to the lambda's role.